# Folder I create in Visual studio is not publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, solution-explorer

In VS2017 Community, I have created a folder that I upload images to. But, I cannot see the images in the solution explorer, it is just blank. Also when I publish my solution, the folders are missing and are not published. There are images in the folder.

I have tried right clicking to include in the project, but this option is not there.

Any suggestions on how I can not only publish the folders but also see the images that are in it (in solution explorer)...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason of this problem can be you are publishing an empty folder but in visual studio if you publish an empty folder then it is not published and it also missed by solution explorer and this is a continues problem of visual studio in this case you have to add a dummy item in folder and then you have to publish may be it can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the files weren't added to the project

[image]

Click that icon - you should than see the files in the folder in the solution explorer and add them to the project by right clicking them